# Base class reference - assign other type to it

Tags: c++, reference

What happens in the following example?

```
struct B { };
struct D1 : B  { };
struct D2 : B  { };
int main()
{
    D1 d;
    D2 d2;
    B& x = d;
    x = d2;
}
```

I know the reference is not re-assigned. `x` still refers to `d`, but then how can you assign `d2` to `d`?

Some more:

```
struct B
{
    B () { x = 0; }
    int x;
    virtual void foo () { cout << "B" << endl; }
};
struct D1 : B
{
    D1 () { x = 1; }
    virtual void foo () { cout << "D1" << endl; }
};
struct D2 : B
{
    D2 () { x = 2; }
    virtual void foo () { cout << "D2" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
D1 d;
D2 d2;
B& x = d;
x.foo();   //D1
               //x.x is 1 here
x = d2;
x.foo();   //also D1
               //but x.x is 2 here
}
```

It seems like `x.x` was updated, but the vftable was not... Why?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`x` refers to the `B` base class *subobject* of `d`. The assignment `x = d2` [*slices*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_slicing) the `B` base subobject from `d2` and assigns its value to the subobject of `d`.

This is usually not done intentionally.

**EDIT:**

> It seems like x.x was updated, but the vftable was not... Why?

That is what the assignment operator `B::operator=` does. Base classes in C++ are totally unaware that they are base classes. Also, the type of an object cannot ever be changed during its lifetime. The closest alternative is C++11's `std::move`, which can transfer the old `B` object inside a `D1` into a fresh `D2` object. You would then destroy the old object.

Comment: Hmm, can copy assignment be made `virtual`, by the way? (too lazy to try / look it up)

Comment: I thought using references prevents slicing... no?

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know this. Actually I didn't think about this before. +1.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Yes, but I'm not sure if that's a good design. I don't do much OO.

Comment: @Potatoswatter Sure, I agree. But – not sure if my brain is working properly at the moment – this would prevent slicing in this context, no? (But yes, I wouldn’t advocate writing such code.)

Comment: @AMCoder Using references prevents slicing as soon as you create the object, but it's still possible.

Comment: @Nawaz shouldn't the question get an upvote then? (wink wink)

Comment: @KonradRudolph You would need double dispatch to make it work, because the base class doesn't understand a derived argument without RTTI.

Comment: So what would happen if I had some virtual methods? Will the override from D2 be called, or the one from D1? Actually, I already tested it, and it's the one from D1. But why?

Comment: @AMCoder I have tried just that, and I get the D1 method. See [here](http://ideone.com/8cHNY)

Comment: Yup, that's it. Forgot about `operator =`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter I don’t think you need double dispatch, `operator=` is a normal function in that regard. See eran’s answer. There’s no double dispatch, and the RTTI is only a correctness check, not strictly necessary to implement the functionality.

Answer (score 3):

If you want, you can implement the = by yourself and "avoid" the slicing by checking for the appropriate concrete type (or giving an error). See below example with errors.

```
struct B { 
  virtual B& operator = (B& b) = 0;
};
struct D1 : B  { 
  D1& operator = (B& b) {
    if ( dynamic_cast<D1*>(&b) == 0 ) {
      cerr << "Cannot assign non D1 to D1" << endl;
      exit(255);
    }
    // handle the assignments
    return *this;
  }
};
struct D2 : B  { 
  int c;
  D2& operator = (B& b) {
    if ( dynamic_cast<D2*>(&b) == 0 ) {
      cerr << "Cannot assign non D2 to D2" << endl;
      exit(255);
    }
    // handle the assignments
    return *this;
  }
};
```

Comment: RTTI makes baby jesus cry. Still, +1

Comment: Oh… note that the entire implementation could be `D &operator=(B const & b) { return * this = dynamic_cast< D const & >( b ); }`, assuming no special semantics are desired. That would throw `std::bad_cast` on type check failure.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, when you assign this way members, that do not belong to Base class will be sliced. Which means, that in this case it's copied like if your were assigning one Base class object to another.

Comment: Are you talking about object slicing (cause that's what it's called)?

Comment: Yes, I've forgotten this term.