# Calling virtual functions through a reference to the base class

Tags: c++, inheritance, reference

This code refuses to print the appropriate messages to the console when I run it. Using pointers instead of references seems to work (-> instead of .). I am new to OOP so forgive me if you find this ridiculous.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class instrument {
public:
    virtual void play(){}
};

class drum : public instrument {
public:
    void play(){
        cout << "dum, dum" << endl;
    }
};

class piano : public instrument {
public:
    void play(){
        cout << "pling" << endl;
    }
};

int main (){
    instrument i;
    piano p;
    drum d;

    instrument &pi = i;
    pi.play();  // -

    pi = p;
    pi.play();  // pling

    pi = d;
    pi.play();  // dum, dum
}
```

Comment: You cannot change a reference from the object to which it references once it bound at initialization. Right now your firing assignment operators (and triggering [object slicing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c/274634#274634) in the process).

Comment: Make that an answer, will ya, sir?

Comment: A side issue, but you need to make a virtual destructor in the base class.

Comment: @PeterWood: Probably a good idea. But not required as he is not calling the destructor via a base class pointer.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Base class reference - assign other type to it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11065657/base-class-reference-assign-other-type-to-it)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
instrument &pi = i;
```

Here you make `pi` refer to the `instrument` object `i`.

```
pi = p;
```

Here you are assigning the `piano` object `p` to the object referred to by `pi`. The reference `pi` is not rebound to the `piano` object. It still refers to the same `instrument` object as before. It's just that different contents have been assigned to it using the implicitly generated default assignment operator. (In this case, the assignment has no effect, but assigning a derived type to a base type usually results in object slicing.) When you call `pi.play()`, the reference still refers to an `instrument` object and `instrument::play` is executed.

The point is, while you can get a pointer to point at a different object of a different type, you can't do the same with a reference. It always points at the same object. You could fix your code by using multiple references:

```
instrument &pi = i;
pi.play();  // -

instrument &pp = p;
pp.play();  // pling

instrument &pd = d;
pd.play();  // dum, dum
```

Comment: Pointers are a bit more versatile and flexible than references, aren't they?

Comment: @Venom no. both have their uses

Comment: @Venom They might be more flexible if you just consider their raw functionality. However, you don't always want that flexibility. In fact, it might even lead to problems. Pick the appropriate type for the job.

Comment: Yes, pointers _are_ a bit more versatile and flexible. That doesn't mean they don't have their uses, though.

Answer (score 2):

```
int main ()
{ 
    instrument i,*pi;
    piano p;
    drum d; 
    pi= &i; 
    pi->play(); // - 
    pi = &p; 
    pi->play(); // pling
    pi = &d; 
    pi->play(); // dum, dum 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please add an explanation to supplement your code in your post.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
virtual void play() = 0;
```

Instead of:

```
virtual void play(){}
```

It prevents redundant object creation possibility.

Comment: can you explain your answer for better understanding? Thanks.